# Selenium: request-response history

Tags: python, selenium

How can I collect history of requests and responses not only selenium-driven but also made by human in same tab of selenium-driven browser?

Answer (score 0):

i think your question is not clear enough.  since both selenium and the application it interacts with uses HTTP (and therefor request/response)

- if you're looking to record **network traffic from/to the application** , check [chrome DevTools network panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) or [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and other **network sniffing tools**
- however if your interested in recording **all actions performed on
  the application** you need to record **all events fired in the DOM**
  for that [you can start here](https://briangrinstead.com/blog/chrome-developer-tools-monitorevents/)

on both cases, the history you'll be collecting is not affected by who/what perform the action and would record both selenium and humen activities